# How to pass parameter value as a tag for new image?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I need to force user to change the name of an image he wants to push.
User pulls image from jfrog and changes it, then he HAS TO change the name before uploading it to jfrog.

I managed to set a parameter which user can change in the UI, just type something

```
parameters:
- name: "changeName"
  type: string
  default: "newname"
```

Now, in the task docker push, this value "new-name" has to be added to the image name after dash:
[base-image-name]-newname

I want it to look like this:

```
      - task: JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension.artifactory-docker.ArtifactoryDocker@1
        displayName: 'Artifactory Docker Push'
        inputs:
          command: push
          artifactoryService: Jfrog
          targetRepo: 'docker'
          imageName: jfrog-base-image-name-newname
```

I did a PowerShell task which gets this value and adds it to the base image name:

```
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $variable = '${{parameters.addName}}'
            Set-Variable -Name "newname" -Value "base-image-name-$variable"
            Get-Variable -Name "newname"
            Write-Host "$newname";
```

It returns correct new name "base-image-name-newname"

Now, how to actually send this to the task docker push? How this task should look?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the parameter value directly to string base imageName?

I don't have the `JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension.artifactory-docker.ArtifactoryDocker@1` running, but please try something like this:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: changeName
    type: string
    default: newname

#....etc...

     - task: JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension.artifactory-docker.ArtifactoryDocker@1
        displayName: 'Artifactory Docker Push'
        inputs:
          command: push
          artifactoryService: Jfrog
          targetRepo: 'docker'
          imageName: 'jfrog-base-image-name-${{ parameters.changeName }}'
```